# incorrect database displayed in docker container

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

My database is defined as `blue`:-

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  ngxapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: andys
    container_name: ngxapp
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: ngxapp
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  ngxwebserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: ngxwebserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8097:80"
      - "4431:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  ngxdb:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: ngxdb
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3418:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: blue
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

seen here;-

[image]

however, when i go to the terminal and look for it there, it's displaying as `red`:-

[image]

what's happening? I have span up another container with a db defined as `red` previously, but have since deleted and removed it entirely.

I've tried restarting the container with the `--build` flag also, no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably reset your `dbdata` DB [Docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/):

```
volumes:
  - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
  - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Try:

```
docker volume rm dbdata
```

**This will erase all MySQL data**. Next time you do `docker-compose up` MySQL will be initialized from scratch and `blue` DB should be created.

Comment: hmm, `$ docker volume rm dbdata
Error: No such volume: dbdata`

Comment: @cookie try `docker volume ls` to see which volumes you have. I took `dbdata` from your docker-compose file.

Comment: You were on the right path Anton. I used the `-f` flag with your command and it works, thanks.